# handsontable with floating scrollbar plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, handsontable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNfXm.png)I am using handsontable library and I want floating horizantal scrollbar to bottom of the screen, when the handsontable horizantal scrollbar is not visible. Because for scrolling horizantally every time goes down to the handsontable scrollbar.I tried with postion fixed property but handsontable library set CSS styles and it get mis-aligned.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uI6S.png)

Comment: please add some code

Comment: I have added two image in first you can see the half table is shown but the horizontal scrollbar is missing and in the second image you can see the whole table is shown with the horizontal scrollbar at bottom.

So I want floating horizontal scrollbar in the first scenario when the horizontal scrollbar is missing.

Comment: *I tried with postion fixed property but handsontable library set CSS styles and it get mis-aligned* – please provide a [mcve]